# CSS - making a div clickable... some problems

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a div that I want to make clickable. This div has nothing inside but has a background image that represents the button state off. When the user hovers the div using a mouse, I want the button to change to state on. When the mouse is not hovering the div I want the button to return to off.

Another thing is this: when the user clicks, I want the button to change to ON for a brief period, lets say 0.2 seconds and then return to OFF. Then the div's url must be followed.

Problems I am facing right now:

1. When the mouse hovers the div the browser did not show the finger that denotes that the region is clickable;
2. when the user clicks the div changes the background image to ON (thats fine) but it stays ON unless I refresh the page.

This is my div

```
<div id="button1" onclick="location.href='http://www.mysite.com';this.id='button1_on';return false;">   </div>
```

this is the css

```
#button1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:159px;
    top:466px;
    width:119px;
    height:120px;
    background-image:url('images/buttonOFF.jpg');
    background-repeat:no;
        background-position: left top;
}

#button1_on {
    position:absolute;
    left:159px;
    top:466px;
    width:119px;
    height:120px;
    background-image:url('images/buttonON.jpg');
    background-repeat:no;
        background-position: left top;
}
```

How do I make the image return to OFF after a brief period, change it to ON on hover and force the browser to show the finger...

another question just as curiosity: is there a way to make it without using all that code inside the div? I would rather to let the divs clean.

Comment: Looks like you're changing the location when the element is clicked, so how would that work with changing the background ?

Comment: Clickable elements should be buttons (unless they are causing a navigation and then they should be anchors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your CSS:

```
#button1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:159px;
    top:466px;
    width:119px;
    height:120px;
    background-image:url('images/buttonOFF.jpg');
    background-repeat:no;
    background-position: left top;
}

#button1:hover,
#button1:active {
    background-image:url('images/buttonON.jpg');
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and don't change the ID using JavaScript.

EDIT: also, is there a reason you don't simply use an  tag? Those work even in browsers without JS, and you know.. they're kinda designed for the exact purpose of taking people to other sites on click.

EDIT 2: removed unneccesary properties from the :hover and :active.

Answer (score 2):

This will set the pointer how you want

```
#button1 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem:

```
When the mouse hovers the div the browser did not show the finger that denotes that the region is clickable;
```

use `cursor:pointer`

```
#button1:hover {

cursor:pointer
}
```

For your second problem add:

```
#button1:active {

    background-image:url('images/buttonON.jpg');


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this on your buttons on hover `cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;`. And put the `onclick` code in a separate javascript script.

Comment: I tried using cursor hand, but it says invalid property value

Comment: I see, apparently, it was supported by the older versions of IE such as ie5.x but since we don't care about those anymore, you could just ignore it... If you still care about IE5.x then put the cursor: hand before the cursor: pointer and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, to make your cursor look like the button pointer, use this CSS:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Second, to move the JavaScript from the DIV to JavaScript, include a `<script>...</script>` tag in your `<head>` or link a script file via `<script src="mycode.js"></script>`, where mycode.js will contain your code.